# Why can't install CSR reply in my Windows keystore?

Tags: java, windows, cryptography, csr

I'm wondering if it is possible to install a CSR reply (signed x509 with its chain) after creation of an entry on Windows-MY keystore, using java of course.

I couldn't find any information or example, so I suppose that is not possible, but I would like to know why.

Any info will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, a "CSR reply" is a certificate. There is a process for IIS (generate the key, generate the CSR, then add the certificate once signed to the machine store), but I've never seen a workflow or tool for user data.

Comment: Thank you for your help. What I need specifically, is to install programmatically a third party signed X509 directly into windows' keystore (not using PFX). Regards.